# Computing cubic polynomial

Tags: scheme, racket, polynomial-math

I need a procedure that returns the value of a cubic polynomial, ie :

> f(x) = x<sup>3</sup> + ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c

I should be able to do this with a procedure that takes three arguments and Newton-Raphson's method but I am at a loss on how.

```
(define f (cubic a b c) ...)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please note that "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  What have you tried so far?  What didn't work about it?

Comment: Newtown's method is useful for (but not guarnteed) to find roots of a function. Finding the value at any particular x is a different beast.

Comment: You have misunderstood either the problem or the solution. There's no point in trying to use Newton-Raphson to compute the *value* of a polynomial for a given input.

Answer (score 2):

Well you want your function to return a function so

```
(define cubic
   (lambda (a b c) ;; lambda #1
      (lambda (x) ;; lambda #2
        ???))) ;; x^3 a * x^2 + b * x + c
```

This is called a closure, lambda 2 is returned when lambda 1 is called and can remember and access the parameters from lambda #1's call.

Then

```
(define f (cubic a b c))
```

defines f to be a function taking in `x` and plugging it into lambda #2's body.